# MiniTest::Assertion: StandardError expected but nothing was raised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I am using minitest for tests for my ruby on rails. I have a problem in it, what I was try to do was stubbing a method to return exception. And check if exception raises.

```
class MyProject

  def operations

   begin
     perform_addtion
   rescue StandardError => e
    puts e
   end

  end
  
  def perform_addition
   */ some code */ 
  end
end
```

I was trying to manually raise exception from **perform_addition** method like this

```
def test_my_project
  MyProject.any_instance.expects(:perform_addition).raises(StandardError)
  assert_raises StandardError do
    MyProject.new.operations
  end
end
```

The thing is I can see the stubbed exception is raised and control goes to the rescue block in **operations** method  when I checked with debugger but assert_raises fails and throws **StandardError expected but nothing was raised**
Can someone tell why its like this. Then how can I check if the rescue is executed

Comment: Well, since you rescued that exception, it's not going to be raised outside. As for how do you test whether control reaches a certain section — this is not a very practical test target. You want to test method's **outputs**: a **value** that it may return, raise or throw. Say, you could return a very specific value from that `rescue` or re-raise the error.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a probably proper solution for this case. I think it's self-explanatory, but feel free to ask questions of any kind

The app:

```rb
class MyProject

  # you can omit begin, and in methods, you can just write rescue
  def operations
    perform_addtion
  rescue StandardError => e
    puts e

    # Your rescue "ate" your exception, so you need to raise it again
    raise e
  end

  # add a raise to test
  def perform_addition
    raise StandardError
  end
end
```

The test:

```rb
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/mock'

require_relative 'my_project'

class MyProjectTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_operations

    # create mock for MyProject
    mock_my_project = Minitest::Mock.new

    # create stub for MyProject
    def mock_my_project.operations
      raise StandardError
    end

    # use stub in test
    MyProject.new.stub :operations, mock_my_project do
      assert_raises StandardError do
        MyProject.new.operations
      end
    end
  end
end
```